# Applying modulo to all elements of a python list and getting some correct some incorrect elements

Tags: python, list, loops

I am implementing a function that reduces all the elements of a list modulo 3. Here is what I have:

```
def reduceMod3(l):
    for i in l:
        l[i] = l[i] % 3
    return l
```

when I call this function on L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] I get:

```
L = [1, 2, 0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 8, 0]
```

Why is this? I am trying to figure it out but I'm in a rush. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

When you write `for i in l`, you are accessing each element of the list, not the index. Instead, you should write

```
for i in range(len(l)):
```

You can also solve this with a list comprehension:

```
return [item % 3 for item in l]
```

Comment: it's weird to call it `i` in `[... for i in l]`, since `i` is typically (and indeed used here as) an index variable.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of personal preference. I usually use names like i,j,x,y for indexing into list comprehensions.

Comment: right, but it's not an index. You see how that's confusing, right? :P YMMV, and it's not *wrong*, but it's just confusing especially as an answer to a question being asked due to a confusion between elements and indices.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll change it for clarity

Answer (score 1):

You're list assignment is off, `l[i]` is not saying 'the value that equals `i`' but 'position `i` in list `l`'. You also don't want to modify a list as you iterate over it.

I think this is more what you want. Creates a new list of mod3 items of the incoming list.

```
def reduceMod3(l):
    return [i % 3 for i in l]
```

Comment: there's actually no harm in modifying a list as you iterate over it, so long as you don't append or delete from the list.

Comment: @AdamSmith You are correct. I was messed up thinking that something might go wrong as he was incorrectly setting `l[i]` as the item in `i`, but that would more cause issue with IndexError if that happened.